# Does ASP.NET reads assemblies only once at startup?

Tags: asp.net

When asp.net application starts is it true that it reads the assemblies only once?

I mean no disk IO operations are made for website assemblies after startup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, they are loaded in with the `AppDomain` on start up once.

Comment: I guess it's true only for web applications not for websites, isn't it ??

Comment: @yogi it's the same scenario for websites as well (AFAIK). The only difference with web sites is when you reference assemblies they either need to be in the `bin` folder or the GAC otherwise they won't get loaded (which more often than not leads to a noticeable issue with your site...).